# How to keep only one entry among several in PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, inner-join, sql-delete

I have a database that monitors a network (snapshots table, that contains a snapshot_date column). This production database was flooded by a faulty crontab, resulting in many snapshots for the same device every day.

[image]

I don't won't to remove everything, but i want to keep only one snapshot per snapshot_date and per device_id (column type is "timestamp without time zone") so to reduce the number of entries in this table.

I don't know any simple mechanism to do this in plain SQL. Can this be achieved ?

Comment: Is snapshot_id unique/a PK?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (snapshot_date, device_id) *
from mytable 
order by snapshot_date, device_id, snapshot_id
```

This retains the one row per `snapshot_date` and `device_id` that has the smalles `snapshot_id`. Note that this assumes that `snapshot_id` is unique (or, at least, is unique for each `(snapshot_date, device_id)` tuple).

If you wanted a `delete` statement, then:

```
delete from mytable t
using (
    select snapshot_date, device_id, min(snapshot_id) snapshot_id
    from mytable 
    group by snapshot_date, device_id
) t1
where 
    t.snapshot_date = t1.snapshot_date
    and t.device_id = t1.device_id
    and t.snapshot_id < t1.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `snapshot_id` is a primary key indeed. However snapshot_date is a date time (timestamp without a timezone). It follows the following format : `2020-10-14 03:49:59`. My problem being, i have loads of snapshots for the same device for the same date (i.e. in this example `2020-10-14`) with many different hours. I would like to the latest for each device, and delete every other else (one snapshot per date).

Comment: @MathiasB.: ok, that was not obvious from your question. You can use `snapshot_date::date` instead.